# How to know if a Topic creation is "submitted" to console (Firebase Cloud Messaging)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using google Firebase with xCode (swift). I need to create Topic dynamically, due to user selection.

Yesterday I created a topic with:

```
FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/\(button.titleLabel?.text!)")
```

And I waited for topic creation in console, i've saw that it takes max 1 day, but nothing.

I've also created a new topic Programmatically (and not dynamically) with this code:

```
FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/Notifiche")
```

and it worked without problem (I've waited for creation for 4/5 hours)..

My question is: **there is a method that let me now if topic is "in creation"?** Because I don't know if my code is wrong, subscribe() method didn't say anything

Thank you all!

Comment: there is no method to check in creation, but you can check by sending notification to that topic

Comment: But in my console, that topic is not present. So, why send notification to a topic that don't exists?

Comment: it is created when you subscribe to any topic, but it takes some time to show in console

Comment: @HamzaAnsari yes I know. But right know I can't know if I made a mistake in code

Comment: Thats not possible right now, firebase doesn't give any feedback for that it retries if subscription fails

Comment: *firebaser here* As Hamza says: topics are automatically created when you subscribe to them or send to them. It takes up to a few hours before new topics show up in the console, but they are already usable before that. If messages are not reaching the device, it has to be due to some other reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found.

It takes few hours to add topic to console, but it's already usable before that, as said.

You cannot know it through Firebase console, but you can do an HTTP Request in order to know if you are subscribed to that particular topic.

### HTTP REQUEST

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/<input token here>?details=true
```

**How to take token**

```
FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
```

#### COMPLETE CODE

**(This code let you unsubscribe from all topics)**

```
    func unsubscribe_topics(){


    let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token();

    let url = URL(string: "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/\(token!)?details=true")

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"


        //define the multipart request type


        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("key=<insert server key here>", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")


        let session = URLSession.shared


        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in

            guard let _:NSData = data as NSData?, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }


            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

            let dati_da_string = dataString?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
            let parsedData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dati_da_string!) as! NSDictionary
            if let rel = parsedData?["rel"] {
                let relaz = rel as! NSDictionary
                let topics = relaz["topics"] as! NSDictionary
                let topics_registrati = topics.allKeys as! [String]
                for i in 0...(topics_registrati.count-1){
                    FIRMessaging.messaging().unsubscribe(fromTopic: "/topics/\(topics_registrati[i])")
                    print("Unsubscibed from: \(topics_registrati[i])")
                }
            }



        }

        task.resume()

    }
```